# Expectation of stochastically bounded expression.

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-approximation, expected-value

For any $\mu>1/2$ let $Y_\mu \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\mu)$ and let $c<\mu$.

Define 
$$
X_{\mu} = \frac{Y_\mu+c-\mu}{\mu},
$$
and then one can realise (pretty sure I have established this) that
$$
\log(1+X_\mu) = X_\mu -\frac{1}{2}X_\mu^2 + \mathcal{O}_p(X_\mu^3), \quad \text{as } \mu\to\infty
$$
which by [definition of Big O' in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation) means that $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists $M>0$ and $\mu_0>0$ such that 
$$
P \left( \left| \frac{\log(1+X_\mu) -X_\mu + \frac{1}{2}X^2_\mu }{X^3_\mu}  \right|> M \right)  < \epsilon \quad \text{for all } \mu>\mu_0.
$$

Now I want to establish some kind of normal Big O' statement of the expectation of this expression. More specifically I want something like

$$
E\log(1+X_\mu) = EX_\mu -\frac{1}{2}EX_\mu^2 + \mathcal{O}(EX_\mu^3), \quad \text{as } \mu\to \infty
$$
because this would allow me to derive what I want to show, which is 
$$
E\log(1+X_\mu) = EX_\mu -\frac{1}{2}EX_\mu^2 + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{\mu^2} \right), \quad \text{as } \mu\to \infty,
$$
since $EX_\mu^3 =\frac{c^3+3c\mu+\mu}{\mu^3} = \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{\mu^2} \right)$ as $\mu\to \infty$.

**Problem:** How do I derive the $\mathcal{O}$ statement with the expectations from the $\mathcal{O}_p$ statement?